# Application label did not work

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have `android:label="Name app"` in `<application`
and `android:label="Activity name"` in `<activity`
(all in androidmanifest.xml)

and if i install this app on real device, this app have name "Activity name" 
why ?  How can i change app name ?

edit1

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher2"
        android:label="Dog"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <activity
            android:name=".FirstActivity"
            android:label="Cat"
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".secondActivity">
        </activity>
        </application>
```

and app still have name Cat in my phone

[image: hot to do it ?]

Comment: "this app have name "Activity name"" -- where **specifically** are you looking for this name?

Comment: in phone menu, under icon this app

Answer (score 0):

> in phone menu, under icon this app

That is not the label of the application. That is the label of the specific activity that has the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` in your manifest. If you want to change this label, change the `android:label` on that `<activity>` element.

The `android:label` on `<application>` serves as the default label (for `<activity>` elements that lack one) and is used in places like the Settings app.

Comment: whether it is possible, before to turning applications see a different name than when you turn on the top bar?

Comment: @Rambo: I do not know what "turning applications" means, and I do not know what "turn on the top bar" means, sorry.

Comment: When you enter the menu of your phone, you see the applications icons and their names. When you enter the application you see name of the activity. I want this same name of the activity and name in menu

Comment: @Rambo: "When you enter the menu of your phone, you see the applications icons and their names" -- I am going to assume that "the menu of your phone" means the home screen's app launcher. Perhaps you have a poorly-written home screen. A home screen's app launcher is supposed to show icons of *launchable activities*, not of applications. "I want this same name of the activity and name in menu" -- both are controlled by the `android:label` attribute on the `<activity>` element, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @Rambo: If you change `android:label` on your `<activity>`, and the change does not appear on the home screen's launcher icon for that activity, try uninstalling and reinstalling your app, or try rebooting your phone.

Comment: did not work, if i change label in <activity>, also changes the name of an icon, my friend have this same problem on other computer,android studio and phone

Comment: @Rambo: "if i change label in <activity>, also changes the name of an icon" -- that is what you said that you wanted ("I want this same name of the activity and name in menu ").

Comment: check my next edit, this is my problem, i using google translator so sometimes no one understand me

Comment: @Rambo: As I wrote previously, try uninstalling and reinstalling your app, or try rebooting your phone. If neither help, then the home screen used on your device has bugs. The home screen launcher should be using the launcher activity label, not the application label. If there are bugs in the home screen, there is nothing much that you can do about that.

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling and rebooting your phone did not help :(